# Include an item in 2 different scrollviewers

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a grid divided into 4 grids A, B, C & D. I need to enable a horizontal scrollviewer only for 2 grids A and B. However, I need to enable a vertical scrollviewer only for 2 grids B & D. How can grid B be included in both the first horizontal scrollviewer and the second vertical scrollviewer?
Thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

Edit: Maximizing the window always makes it positioned on the left upper part of the window as depicted in the image below:

[image]

Here's the code I added for making sure the maximized window is positioned away from the upper left region. However, nothing changes about this issue!

```
    private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
        //   Left = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - Width;
           Left = 200;
         //  Top = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - Height;
          Top = 200;          
        }
    }
```

Any hints for keeping the window centered in the maximizing mode? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify your question and give us the code you've tried that is not working, I'm having a hard time understanding what you want. A UniformGrid is a Grid that has unified cell size, you don't specify how many rows and columns your UniformGrid has, I assume it's 2x2 but who knows. Each cell are individual, they don't share their bounds/items together, meaning a ScrollViewer inside cell A cannot 'extend' itself inside cell C. Maybe a UniformGrid is not what you're exacly looking at, but I don't have enough information.

Comment: Thanks very much for your concern. Well, I'm sorry I meant a grid not a uniform grid. It's a normal grid divided into 4 minor grids. I need 1 minor grid to be included in a horizontal scrollviewer with 1 other grid and included in a vertical scrollviewer with another grid. Could this be attained? Thanks again.

Comment: After looking at the added picture, I'm still confused on what you want to achieve. Does the horizontal `ScrollViewer` would move A and B at the same time or does A and B needs to have their own separate `ScrollViewer`? Same thing for B and D, are they sharing the same `ScrollViewer` or do they have their own ones? What will be shown inside each cell? Maybe that will help to get a sense of what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need grid A and B to move horizontally at the same time. That's the case as well with B and D but vertically. Thanks a lot for your help, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're not really interested in a UniformGrid, but rather looking for a way to have a vertical ScrollViewer inside an horizontal ScrollViewer.

This code gives you a 2x2 Grid :
A B
C D

The first element added is an horizontal ScrollViewer that span inside both A and C, this element is divided in two, the bottom part has a vertical ScrollViewer.
The elements in B and D are simple elements.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000"/>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Image Source="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Source="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000"/>
    <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000"/>
</Grid>
```

EDIT

Here's a new code to suit the requirements in your edit.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="A" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollChanged="A_ScrollChanged">
        <Image Stretch="None" Source="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="B" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollChanged="B_ScrollChanged">
        <Image Stretch="None" Source="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="C" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Image Stretch="None" Source="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="D" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollChanged="D_ScrollChanged">
        <Image Stretch="None" Source="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
    private void A_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        B.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset);
    }

    private void B_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        A.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset);
        D.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.VerticalOffset);
    }

    private void D_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        B.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.VerticalOffset);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your code is helpful but what If I need to add an item inside your vertical scrollviewer and I don't want it to be included in the horizontal scrollviewer? I'll try to post a photo of what I mean so that it can be clearer. Thanks again.

Comment: I've just posted a photo in the question. Please, have a look.

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried your code but there seems to be something wrong in my implementation, I don't know! The scrollviewers are now enabled but inactive (don't scroll with dynamically adding more elements to the grid). I'll post my XML in the question; I'm very thankful for your help.

Comment: Well, it's now working properly! The problem was that I have to assign a fixed width to the horizontal scrollviewer. Thanks very very much, I'm really grateful to you. I'll mark your answer as accepted but I just have another question if you please, what if I need to make the vertical scrollviewer on the right side of the grid not on the left side? Is this possible? Plus, do you think WPF with C# is a convenient tool for generating grids of huge size? I noticed some lag when I tried to increase the number of cells on a grid! Any recommendations will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: [Here's a link to an example from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847(v=vs.85).aspx) that shows how to customize ScrollViewer to show on left side instead of right side, it's basically just applying a style and putting the `ScrollBar` element on the first column (left) of a `Grid` and the `ScrollContentPresenter` on the second column (right).

Comment: For large number of elements, a `Grid` is not the best control, you should use a control that can take advantage of UI Virtualization, like `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` (ListBox inherits from ItemsControl). [See here for some more information.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Mr. Roger, you're such a kind person. I'll have a look at the links you provided. One more question if you please, maximizing this window always makes it positioned on the left upper region of the screen and with a certain width and height no matter what maximum width or height I set. I set the window's left and top values in the WindowStateChanged event on condition that the new state is maximized; I want it to be centered. However, the maximized window always shows up on the upper left region and with a certain width different than the maximum width! Any hints, if you please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's your issue, but setting `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth` properties to the `Grid` element makes it centered in the screen without exceeding the maximum width and height specified, no matter if the window is maximized or not. Code : `<Grid MaxHeight="100" MaxWidth="100">`

Comment: Yes, I get your point but I don't know what is wrong in particular. Maximizing the window makes it positioned on the left upper region of the screen i.e: not in the center any more! The maximized window is always on the left upper part even though I set Left=200 and Top=200 in the Window_StateChanged event on the condition of maximizing. I'll post the code in the question.

Comment: I think this conversation has sideloaded a lot from its original question, to make sure I or someone else can help you better, you should start another question with the bare minimum code to reproduce your issue, I suggest you start over with an empty app and only include enough code to reproduce, without even including your 4 cells if they aren't needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm sorry you're right. I've posted another question regarding this issue. I apologize for asking so many questions and loads of thanks for helping me. Here's the link of the new question :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599712/c-sharp-wpf-maximized-windows-position